# Can't write at all to Aurora PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to migrate an existing Rails application from a PostgreSQL RDS instance to Aurora PostgreSQL Serverless v2. I have created a new database for Aurora PostgreSQL Serverless v2 and successfully ran AWS DMS to migrate data.

However, I am now facing a ton of "null value in column x" errors even for basic WRITE statements:

```
dev=> INSERT INTO bots (name) VALUES ('hello world');
ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "bots" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, hello world, null, null, null, null, null).
db=> exit
```

This happens when writing to literally any table.

Is this related to a faulty migration of some sort? I wasn't connected to the source db at all during the duration of the migration, so I can't wrap my head around what may be causing this.

The closest thing I've been able to find related to this is https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dms-error-null-value-column/, but I have used "Limited LOB" in the migration task. I think I'm going down the wrong path with the troubleshooting process.

Comment: How is the "id" supposed to get populated?  Apparently it isn't working, but we don't know what it is that isn't working.  A sequence?  A uuid?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.